# How to insert a object which has a list of objects in it?

Tags: hibernate

ContentPack class,

```
@Entity
public class ContentPack {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Property
private String name;

@OneToMany  // ????
private List<ContentItem> songsList;
}
```

Next the ContentItem class,

```
@Entity
public class ContentItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String mp3Url;
}
```

but when i try to call the following,

```
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(contentPack);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

i get the following error. I believe the `list` creates the error. How can i fix it?

Error :

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize songsList with blank/empty list , like :

```
private List<ContentItem> songsList = new ArrayList<ContentItem>();
```

I am not sure whether this will solve the issue or not . if not then can you share detail code for the saving **ContentPack** and how you are setting **ContentItem** in it.

Comment: all these have getters and setters. So they work fine.The problem is from Hibernate side. I need to find the correct way of annotating them

Comment: Can try without annotation. You will refer to [link](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html) , it contain nice simple example anyone can understand it.